# Replace value of index at unkown depth of multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

Lets suppose we have a multidimensional nested array that looks like bellow.

How to replace the array at index `e` with a new Array?

```
Array(
[a]=>Array(
           [b]=>Array(
                     [c]=>Array(
                               )
                     [d]=>Array(
                                [e]=>Array() 
                               )
                     )
          )
     )
```

Comment: you will have to write a recursive key search for the array.

Comment: overwrite value at key `e` with array `$dummy`: `$dummy = ['dummy']; $arr['a']['b']['d']['e'] = $dummy;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function replaceInArray(&$array, $index, $newVal) {

    if(isset($array[$index])) {
        $array[$index] = $newVal;
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        replaceInArray($value, $index, $newVal);
    }

}



$a = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => 5
        ]
    ]
];

var_dump($a);


replaceInArray($a, 'c', 6);

var_dump($a);
```

Function accept your array, key and new value for this key.